# Removing all Date occurrences in a JSON

Tags: java, date

I have a JSON response that has a lot of real time dates inside it. For example: "2017-01-01T22:54:24.931Z".

How can I remove every occurrence of a date and replace it with null or empty string (via Java code)?

Comment: What JSON library are you currently using?  Simple JSON, GSON, something else?

Comment: Simple JSON library. I am allowed to use Regex.

Comment: Unless you exactly know the structure of the underlying object, a regex solution won't always work. You should just parse and detect the strings which look like dates.

Comment: Using regex and no json library would be simpler. Depends if string similar to date could be included in non-date fileds.

Comment: If you don't care about time, you can iterate over every element and replace those that match your regex.

Comment: Any date / Time value is bad for me. I just need to replace them all with null or "" empty String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could answer your need. Read the whole file content in a String s, then:

```
    s = s.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}Z", "");
```

Then all dates in the specified format will be removed from the String

This code does not verify date validity (eg 2018-20-20...), but probably not necessary for you.

Answer (score 0):

Below link have few options to work with json date deserialization.

```
if (window.JSON && !window.JSON.dateParser) {
    var reISO = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*))(?:Z|(\+|-)([\d|:]*))?$/;

    JSON.dateParser = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            var a = reISO.exec(value);
            if (a)
                return null;

        }
    }
}
```

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates#Caveats-of-overriding-JSON-Parsing

If your using Java and jakson consider using @JsonDeserialize to interpret and assign new value to JSON date fields.

The @JsonDeserialize annotation tells Jackson to use a custom deserializer while deserializing the JSON to Java object. 
To do so, you need to annotate the field to which you need to apply the custom deserializer.

A Java class that uses the @JsonDeserialize annotation is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import guru.springframework.blog.jsonannotation.domain.custom.CustomDateDeserializer;
import java.util.Date;
public class DeserializeDemoBean {
    public long personId = 123L;
    public String  name = "James Clark";
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    public Date activeDate;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DeserializeDemoBean{" +
                "personId=" + personId +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", activeDate=" + activeDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The custom deserializer that is referenced by the preceding DeserializeDemoBeanbean class is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {
    private static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    public CustomDateDeserializer(){
        this(null);
    }
    public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> c){
        super(c);
    }
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext
            deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            //Check or implement any custom logic or include Regex patter to identify date pattern and return null or empty
            return null;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-annotations-for-json-part-3-deserialization